# Блок фиксированного размера между динамическими блоками

Tags: html, css

Как организовать стили и разметку, чтобы средний блок фиксированного размера находился между двумя динамическими блоками

```css
.left {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black dotted;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
  min-height: 230px;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black dotted;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.middle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px black dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

При попытке указать для боковых элементов

```
 width:100%;
```

Они растягиваются на всю ширину над/под остальными блоками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый первый конкурент flexbox это css-table, вот яркое доказательство

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.c {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="l">
    блок роизвольного размера
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    блок в 200 пикселей
  </div>
  <div class="r">
    блок роизвольного размера
  </div>
</div>
```

На всякий случай [почитайте](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281254/) о самой кроссбраузерной вёрстке

Comment: спасибо, особенно за ссылку, открыло глаза на некоторые проблемы. но есть вопрос. если боковые блоки не заполнены, все хорошо. как только мы добавляем новый элемент, допустим, в левый блок, происходит такое https://jsfiddle.net/h1rav306/

Comment: поправил проблему добавление блока-распорки

Answer (score 1):

С помощью flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.left {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px black dotted;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.right {
  min-height: 230px;
  border: 1px black dotted;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px black dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: мог бы выбирать два ответа, выбрал бы оба. но пока к флексбоксам отношусь настороженно, не все браузеры поддерживаются

Answer (score 0):

Доработал ответ [Geyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/33274/geyan), который отлично работает, когда боковые элементы пустые. 
Как только мы помещаем в них другие элементы, верстка рушится. Проблему решил добавлением псевдоблока-распорки в боковые блоки.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.middle {
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar-spacer::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    min-width: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left sidebar-spacer">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    блок в 200 пикселей
  </div>
  <div class="right sidebar-spacer">
  </div>
</div>
```